# Attribute error connect four

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code for my connect four game. I'm trying to create GUI for the game but error's keep coming up, anyone know how to help?

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'font'

```
self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.mw, text = "". font == ('Arial 30 bold'), command = lambda:self.clicked_btn(0, 0), height = 5, width = 10)
    self.button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.buttons_2d_list[0][0] = self.button1
```

Comment: `"".` should be `"",`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a period after text = "" This makes python think you are accessing the font attribute of the string ""

Comment: what should I change that line to?

Comment: just put a comma instead of a period, look at what melpomeme wrote